# Customized Royalslider Thumbnail script

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm using Royalslider, I'm trying to set up an external thumbnail list that when you click one of the thumbs or hit the next button/use arrow key/swipe that thumbnail changes classes to become the "highlighted" thumbnail.  It works well when you click the thumbnail but I can't get it to work with the swiping/keyboard/or next/prev arrows.

I've been trying to go through Public Methods to come up with a script for this but am having a hard time:
 mySliderInstance.numSlides           // Number of slides
    mySliderInstance.currentSlideId      // Current slide id
    mySliderInstance.lastSlideId         // Last(previous) slide id
    mySliderInstance.sliderWidth         // Slider width
    mySliderInstance.sliderHeight        // Slider height

and looking at this example

```
<script>
//Example, replacing arrows with arrow symbols and adding "1 / 5" naigation
var mySliderInstance = $('#sliderId').royalSlider({
    slideTransitionSpeed:400,
    beforeLoadStart:function() {                    
        $("p.navId").text((this.currentSlideId+1) + "/"  +   (this.numSlides) );
        this.arrowLeft.html("&larr;");
        this.arrowRight.html("&rarr;");
    },
    beforeSlideChange:function() {
        $("p.navId").text((this.currentSlideId+1) + "/"  +   (this.numSlides) );
    }       
}).data("royalSlider");
</script>
```

to come up with something.  I use

```
$("#makingof_goto").click(function() {
    sliderInstance.goTo(0);
});
```

Is there a way to modify the script using the mySliderInstance.currentSlideId in a way that could match the slide numbers with the thumbnail.  Like when onslide 3 change the class of #this_thumb to .current_class and then all of the other thumbs in the li list to .unselected doing something like this:

```
$(function() {
$(".hd ul li").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
$("#space_goto").click(function() {
    sliderInstance.goTo(1);
    });
})
});
```

This is the last thing I need to do before I send out my portfolio and I've been battling this for acouple days with no luck, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of royalslider are you using.. just so i know what API options you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
// triggers after slide change
 // Add class to the current thumbnail
 $(".thumb:eq("+slider.currSlideId+")").addClass("current");
});
```